# Problems setting up roundcube virtualhost for every subscription on server

Tags: apache, virtualhost, plesk, roundcube

Im trying to finish the set up of roundcube by adding a virtualhost so every subscription on server will use the webmail.servername.com to access it.

I have uploaded this roundcube.conf file with the code:

```
<VirtualHost  ip-one:7080 \ ip-two:7080 \ local-ip:7080>
ServerName roundcube.webmail
ServerAlias roundcube.webmail.*
ServerAdmin "fdmatte@gmail.com"

DocumentRoot "/var/www/roundcube/"
<Directory "/var/www/roundcube/">
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off

  </IfModule>

  # This is needed to parse /var/lib/roundcube/.htaccess. See its
  # content before setting AllowOverride to None.
  AllowOverride All
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

The issues im having are the following:

1. Using this file when i access my a website like http://www.mywebiste.com it gets routed to http://mywebsite.com
2. When i access webmail.mywebsite.com roundcube gets loaded but it cant find included files like css and js

It only works correctly if i access the ip-one:7080, then it works fine load up all css and js and i can login, check and send emails.

Is there something wrong with my settings?
Im using a plesk 11.5.30

Answer (score 0):

Redirect http://www.mywebiste.com -> http://mywebsite.com can be switched off in Domain's hosting setting it's "Preferred domain" dropdown

Second issue can appears if you have wildcard subdomain *.mywebiste.com, this is well know plesk 11.5 bug so you can just ask Paralles support for solution. (You can workaround it by youself via customizing virtual hosting templates, but you should know how all this plesk backend works).

It's works for ip-one:7080 because Plesk 11.5 don't configure nginx webmail's config for every domain, just for wildcard webmail.*. So, nginx choose "wrong" virtual server and point it to virtual server of this wildcard subdomain which has location "/internal-nginx-static-location/" where static files will be looking by nginx(he know that is is static files because Plesk apache module mod_aclr2 provide such info for him ),  but this location point to vhost folder of subdomain.

It's maybe something else, but I can't say more accurate just by your description.